# How to make vuex getter from data from google api docs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

I'm trying to make getter in vuex store with flat data from google dosc api. All what I need is to take textRun content and keep this in array (because there will be few messages). Now I hardcoded this response in state like:

```
 state: {
    googleResponse: [
      {
        "body": {
          "content": [
            {
              "endIndex": 75,
              "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "endIndex": 75,
                    "startIndex": 1,
                    "textRun": {
                      "content": "This is an ordinary paragraph. It is the first paragraph of the document",
                      "textStyle": {}
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                  "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                  "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT"
                }
              },
              "startIndex": 1
            },
            {
              "endIndex": 102,
              "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "endIndex": 102,
                    "startIndex": 75,
                    "textRun": {
                      "content": "Here's a level one heading",
                      "textStyle": {}
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                  "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                  "headingId": "h.o1fkftgl5zwf",
                  "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1"
                }
              },
              "startIndex": 75
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
}
```

and after that I make a getter `message` and used `map` from lodash:

```
message: (state) => {
  let message = '';
  map(state.googleResponse, (element) => ({
    content: map(element.body.content, (content) => {
      map(content.paragraph.elements, (obj) => {
        message += get(obj, 'textRun', '')
      })
    })
  }))
}
```

But when I'm checking `message` in vuex it says is undefined... I want to have array with textRun objects. Where might be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am wondering whether you can get the message keep in Array by this way?
 you can write like this may your want

```js
   let messageArray = state.googleResponse.map(
        item => item.body.content.map(
            itemCotent => itemCotent.paragraph.elements.map(
                itemElements => itemElements.textRun.content)))
```

Comment: in this way you can get all content info in messageArray

Comment: hmm closer, but after this I think i will get 2 arrays inside array, which will be inside another array. smth like:
[ [ [] [] ] ]

Comment: emm  can  you use es6 programar？Array.flat method can help you;if not;lodash also can  solove it

Comment: let messageArray = state.googleResponse.map(
        item => item.body.content.map(
            itemCotent => itemCotent.paragraph.elements.map(
                itemElements => itemElements.textRun.content))).flat(Infinity)

Comment: sorry my english is not good; hope have some useful advice to you

Comment: not good ? c'mon it's okay :) I used extra flatten on whole and now I have array of objects. So at the end it looks like: `flatten(map(state.googleResponse,
        item => map(item.body.content,
          itemContent => map(itemContent.paragraph.elements,
            itemElements => itemElements.textRun)).flat(Infinity)
      ))`

thx for help!

Comment: yeah i want to study english, i need to come around the wall,in china,it is not convenient to c'mon with foreign counterparts haha ,

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the`message` variable in your getter.